# how to fix routing configuration in cisco packet tracer? (accessing Web server with DNS & router)

Tags: networking, router, webserver

I am trying to build a network in cisco packet tracer and am facing some problems i cant fix.

**The network**

```
                   ROUTER
                     | 
                     |                                          
  3 LAPTOPS -----> SWITCH ----->  2 SERVERS (ones DNS and one is WEB)

          **Interface**        IPV4          Subnet          Gateway

Laptop 1= fastEthernet 0   - 192.168.1.2   - 255.255.255.0 - 192.168.1.1
Laptop B= fastEthernet 0   - 192.168.1.3   - 255.255.255.0 - 192.168.1.1
Laptop C= fastEthernet 0   - 192.168.1.4   - 255.255.255.0 - 192.168.1.1
Web Server= fastEthernet 0 - 20.20.20.22   - 255.0.0.0     - 20.20.20.1
DNS Server= fastEthernet 0 - 20.20.20.26   - 255.0.0.0     - 20.20.20.1
Generic Router= 
      GigabitEthernet 0/0 - 192.168.1.1 - 255.255.255.0 - NA
      GigabitEthernet 1/0 - 20.20.20.1 - 255.255.255.0 - NA
```

Everything is connected. The DNS server (`20.20.20.26`) has a record of `www.example.com` assigned to the web servers IP address (`20.20.20.22`)

All the laptops and web server have the DNS setting `20.20.20.26`. The laptops can ping each other. The router can ping the laptops. The servers can ping each other.

The laptop has the error "host unreachable" when I ping the server. The server request timeout when I ping the laptops.

The packet tracer flags up an error at my router but I don't know how to fix this?

Comment: what is your trunking settings on the switch?

Comment: Looks like your Subnet for your Web and DNS servers do not match up with the Subnet you gave your Router. Give them the same Subnet and they should appear on the Network.

Comment: What is the error at the router?